# Calculate difference of numbers in two files

Tags: bash, sed, awk, scripting

Say I have two files where there is one number per line

```
File 1      file 2
0.12        0.11     
0.121       0.454 
....        ....
```

I want to create file or output difference between each number on  to the screen, so that result looks like

```
 0.0099
-0.333
 ......
```

You can use bash/awk/sed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

awk

```
awk '{getline t<"file1"; print $0-t}' file2  #file2-file1
```

Explanation: `getline t <"file1"` gets a line from `file1` and puts its value to variable `t`. `$0` is the current record of `file2` that awk is processing. the rest is just subtraction and printing the result out.

Bash

```
exec 4<"file1"
while read -r line
do
    read -r s <&4
    echo "${line}-${s}" | bc
done <"file2"
exec >&4-
```

Answer (score 10):

Following shows how to get file1 - file2

```
$ cat file1
0.12
0.43
-0.333

$ cat file2
-0.1
-0.2
0.2

$ paste file1 file2 | awk '{print $1 - $2}'
0.22
0.63
-0.533
```

Comment: what if there is a blank line in one of the file

Comment: if there is a blank line it will made as zero in subtraction.

$ cat file1
0.12
0.43
-0.333
10
$ cat file2
-0.1
-0.2
0.2
$ paste file1 file2 | awk '{print $1 - $2}'
0.22
0.63
-0.533
10

Comment: For getting the absolute value `paste  file1 file2| awk -F'\t' 'function abs(x){return ((x < 0.0) ? -x : x)} {print abs($1 - $2)}' > outputFile`

Answer (score 0):

```
# cat f1
0.12
0.121
# cat f2
0.11     
0.454

# pr -m -t -s\  f1 f2 | gawk '{print $1-$2}'
0.01
-0.333
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash:

```
paste file1 file2 | while read a b ; do 
  echo "$a - $b" | bc
done
```

Comment: This solution is too `fork`-heavy for large files (it doesn't need to be.)

Answer (score 0):

```
paste -d - num1 num2 | bc
```

**Edit:**

This version properly handles negative numbers:

```
yes '-' | head -n $(wc -l < num1) | paste -d ' ' num1 - num2 | bc
```

Comment: your 2nd version has a lot of overheads.

Comment: @ghostdog74: A little overhead, maybe, but how does it have a lot?